# Print WordPress username id inside JavaScript

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, users

Hello am trying to print the user id inside an JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Li.re('ab12','$user_id');  
  </script>
```

i wanna output like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Li.re('ab12','12');  
  </script>
```

12 is the number of the login in user.

Is possible inside shortcode?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mycred_link href="'.get_field('incentivised_url', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId).'subid1='.$get_current_user_id.'[/mycred_link]'); ?>
```

The `.$get_current_user_id.` inside the shortcode not works.

Any help?

Comment: `Li.re( 'ab12', '<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>' );`

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ It works :)

Comment: @SallyCJ can you post answers as answers instead of using the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_current_user_id()` to get the ID of the current user, and in your case, you can do so to print the user ID in the JavaScript `Li.re()` call:

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
  Li.re( 'ab12','<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>' );
</script>
```

And yes, you can include the user ID as part of a shortcode: (note that I omitted the `href` parameter for simplicity)

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[mycred_link subid1="' . get_current_user_id() . '"][/mycred_link]' ); ?>
```

PS: Your shortcode was missing the closing `]` tag, so I added it above. All shortcode parameter values should also be wrapped in single/double quotes.

Comment: Im confused, what's **Li.re**?

Comment: Check the question, @Vishwa. It's a method call in JavaScript (just like `Li::re()` or `$Li->re()` in PHP). But regarding what the method actually does, you can ask the question author..

Comment: Oh, sorry Sally, I just woke up and got it mixed up with something else. thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, @Vishwa. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach it, is by using "wp_localize_script()" to create objects from php that you can access from anywhere.

```
//Get User ID
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$userID = $user->roles[0];

//Enqueue script 
wp_register_script( 'script_handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

// Localize the script with new data
$dataArray = array(
    'userID' => $userID,
    'anyother_value' => 'more data'
);
wp_localize_script( 'script_handle', 'object_name', $dataArray );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_handle' );
```

In your separate javascript file you can simply call the object like below.

```
Li.re( 'ab12', object_name.userID );
```

And your shortcode call is not working because ".$get_current_user_id." is not a variable but a function. The correct way is ".get_current_user_id().". And I think your calling it wrong. You need to create a new WP_user object.

```
 <?php
    $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
    $userID = $user->roles[0];
   ?>
   <?php echo do_shortcode( '[mycred_link subid1="' . $userID . '"][/mycred_link]' ); ?>
```